# Vim how to copy to a real (no relative) line number

Tags: vim

I'm working with NeoVim, but for the case I think it's the same if we talk about vim. I have set relative line numbers (`set nu rnu`) and I know how to copy from the line I currently have the cursor to line x with `yxj`, but I need to copy more lines than I can see, so I first go to line 247, then I go back to line 127 and I don't know if there's a way to specify that I want to copy to line number 247 (without subtracting, of course).

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Move to line 247,
- set a mark, e.g. `a`, via `ma`
- move to line 127
- yank from there to the mark `y'a`

All in all: <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

The relevant documentation is `:help change.txt`. I'll highlight a few commands
appearing in the `:help copy-move` sections of the `change.txt` help
documentation (there is much more in there!).

You can use the command line to specify the lines to yank (i.e. copy, see
`:help :y`):

```
:127,247y
```

It also works with relative numbers (and patterns - see `:help range`):

```
" yank lines 25 before cursor through 3 lines after
" cursor
:-25,+3y
```

In addition, if you know where you want to put them you can use the `t`
command (see `:help :t`):

```
" copy lines 10 before cursor through 2 lines after
" cursor to 5 lines after the cursor
:-10,-2t+5
```

You can even mix and match relative and absolute lines (and patterns - see
`:help range`):

```
" copy from line 23 through to 10 lines before cursor to
" line 51
:23,-10t51
```

For completeness there is the `m` command to move (i.e. cut and paste lines,
see `:help :t`):

```
" move lines 12 before the cursor through to the current
" line to line 27
:-12,.m27
```

#### The traces.vim plugin

I find [this plugin](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim) very nice - it highlights ranges for Ex commands as you
type them on the command line (and shows you how the `:substitute` command will
affect your file as you compose it). It really helped me start to use the
command line more. I have this in my vimrc:

```
" fyi: there is extensive help documentation that's not on the github page 

"immediately highlight numerical ranges once you put the comma :N,N
let g:traces_num_range_preview = 1

" window used to show off-screen matches (just 5 since I only want the gist).
let g:traces_preview_window = "below 5new"

" if value is 1, view position will not be changed when highlighting ranges or
" patterns outside initial view position. I like this since I see it all in the
" preview window setting above
let g:traces_preserve_view_state = 1
```